# Show that the Klein bottle is the connected sum of two copies of $\Bbb{R}P^2$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, projective-space, mobius-band, klein-bottle

**Question** How do I show that the Klein bottle is the connected sum of two $\Bbb{R}P^2$'s? More precisely; how do I construct an explicit continuous bijection between the Möbius strip and $\Bbb{R}P^2\setminus D^2$?

**Thoughts** If I can find an explicit continuous bijection between the Möbius strip $M$ and $\Bbb{R}P^2\setminus D^2$ where $D^2$ is the open disc, then I have a homeomorphism because $M$ is compact and $\Bbb{R}P^2\setminus D^2$ is Hausdorff. Then I will glue those $M$'s along their boundary.

I think of $M$ and $\Bbb{R}P^2\setminus D^2$ as the quotient spaces of $I\times I$, but I can't even see a continuous "deformation" between them visually so that I can cook up a continuous bijection according to the picture in my head.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe the following picture of $\mathbb{R}P^2$ will help:

[image]

Just cut out the dark blue $D^2$ and a light blue moebius strip will remain.

Comment: This is nice! But what happens to the red arrows when we cut them? What happens to the orientation?

Comment: When we cut out $D^2$ from $\mathbb{R}P^2$ in this way it has a 'twist' as is witnessed by the red arrow. This twist is of no further topological consequence in $D^2$, it is just a result of the way in which $D^2$ and the moebius strip are glued together.