# Cell decomposition of connected sum of Torus and Klein bottle

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let $K$ be the Klein bottle and $T^2$ the Torus

What is the cell composition of $K \# T^2$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many cell decompositions for this.

One reasonable way might  be to take the standard square quotients for each. The Klein bottle is given by the word $ab^{-1}ab$, and the torus is given by $cdc^{-1}d^{-1}$. Cut along the corner of each, and glue together the words. This gives the quotient of a polygon whose relation is exactly 
$$ab^{-1}abcdc^{-1}d^{-1}.$$

After doing the specified gluings, we can see that this is a CW-complex with $1$ zero cell, $4$ one cells, and a single two cell.

---

On the other hand, if you have seen that that the [klein bottle is the connect sum of two $\mathbb R P^2$'s](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1039819/connected-sum-of-projective-plane-cong-klein-bottle), then we can rewrite the question in the following way:

$$T^2 \# K=(T^2 \# \mathbb RP^2)  \#\mathbb RP^2=\mathbb RP^2 \#\mathbb RP^2\#\mathbb RP^2\#\mathbb RP^2=K \# K $$

where the second equality comes from associativity and the decomposition o $T^2 \# \mathbb RP^2$ into three projective planes (Theorem 2.1 [here](https://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/hitchin/hitchinnotes/Geometry_of_surfaces/Chapter_1_Topology.pdf)) and the final one comes from the associativity of connect sum.

Comment: I'm not sure how to recover the second interpretation from the first, I hope that someone else will pitch in.