# Why isn't $P^2$ with a disk removed homeomorphic to $P^1$?

Tags: algebraic-topology

Recall that $P^2$ can be obtained by attaching a 2 cell to $P^1$. Denote this 2 cell by $B_2$. Now remove an open disk from $B_2$, according to  [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1039819/connected-sum-of-projective-plane-cong-klein-bottle) it should be the Mobius strip. However it seems to me that it should be $P^1$.

My reasoning: With a disk removed, we can deform $B_2$ to its boundary. Using the description of $P^2$ at the beginning, we then conclude that $P^2$ with a disk removed deformation retracted onto $P^1$.

Comment: Do you not believe a Moebius strip deformation retracts to its centerline, taking its boundary to to that centerline twice (which sounds much like $P^1$...)?

Comment: Oh, right! So it does deformation retract onto $\mathbb RP^1$.